# Angular Typed Forms: How To Set FormArray Nested inside FormGroup to null?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, formarray, formgroups

I've been running into a problem trying to get an Angular FormArray, which is nested inside a FormGroup, to take on a value of either an array or null when strict type checking is enabled.

I encountered this problem trying to create a FormGroup that mirrors a standard TypeScript object. All of my standard object fields can be either a value (string, bool, etc.), null, or undefined and I would like a FormGroup that is able to take on the same values. This FormGroup can also have other similar objects nested inside it such as a nested object or array of objects. To mirror this, I created a FormGroup with a nested FormGroup or nested FormArray. The FormGroup typing works perfectly for any FormControls or FormGroups inside the parent FormGroup but I am unable to get the typing to succeed for the FormArray since the FormArray cannot take on a value of null.

Here is a StackBlitz with example code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-typed-formgroup?file=src/app/app.component.ts&view=editor

Here are the models for reference:

```
interface Parent {
  childField?: string | null;
  childObject?: Child | null;
  childList?: Child[] | null;
}

interface Child {
  field?: string | null;
}
```

Here are the FormGroup types for reference:

```
interface ParentForm {
  childField?: FormControl<string | null>;
  childObject?: FormGroup<ChildForm | null>;
  childList?: FormArray<FormGroup<ChildForm | null>>;
  // childList?: FormArray<FormGroup<ChildForm | null> | null>; // TypeScript throws error.
}

interface ChildForm {
  field?: FormControl<string | null>;
}
```

I was able to get the nested FormGroups to accept null by making the nested FormGroups of type `FormGroup<ChildForm | null>`. I expected that I would be able to do the same with the nested FormArray by using a type of `FormArray<FormGroup<ChildForm | null> | null>` or something similar, but I have been unable to get the typing to the point where it will accept a null value when calling `form.patchValue({childList: null})`.

Comment: Great first question!

Answer (score 0):

As i know, you could not set "null" for Form Controls.

```
interface ParentForm {
  childList?: FormArray<FormGroup<ChildForm | null>> | never;
}
```

And `pathValue` like this fixed the problem:

```
form.patchValue({
  childField: null,
  childObject: null,
  childList: [],
});
```